# WordPress - Display Custom Field on Post - Pull Post Title and URL

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, custom-fields

Okay, I have the code pulling the custom fields URL and title of the url.  Now I can't seem to get it to show the second featured blog.  Here is the working code.

```
<?php $related = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Featured-Blog", $single=true);

        $related=explode(',',$related);
        $args = array_merge( array('post__in'  => $related, $wp_query->query ) );
        query_posts($args);
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><p class="caption"><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>no related</p>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

This code example here produces two results, which is almost what I want.  Which is caused by the foreach I believe.  I do not want to use the code below, but I need to find a way to add the foreach I think to get it to list all of the featured-blogs if I have more than one.

```
<?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['Featured-Blog']; //key name
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $url )
 echo $key ="<a href='".$url."'>TEST</a><br /><br /><br/>";
?>
```

Here is a screenshot showing my Custom Fields if it helps at all, and the results they are showing on the site. [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/dvw2etgnb/)

Comment: You should add some of your code AND the relevant portion of your screenshot to this question

Comment: redid the post to try to be more clear about what Im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Example 1: You are using the actual word 'TITLE' for the link use `<?php the_title() ?>` instead

Example 2: You are not building link at all. Your `href` attribute is empty. Cut `echo $featured_blog1` and paste it to href attribute to end up like so: `<a href="<?php echo $featured_blog1 ?>"></a>`

Example 3: Same as 2

Also you can delete dose instructions or put them inside `<?php ?>` code so they are not visible to viewers.

Hope this helps.

If you need more info just ask. ;)

Comment: thanks for your quick response.  It's strange, when I put the <?php the_title() ?> in the Example 1 no title shows up at all.

Comment: the bottom two examples Seems to be pulling the title and URL of the this page, and not the title and url of the fields that are filled out in the Custom Field section

Comment: The top example is pulling up both of the custom fields properly how I wanted it, but just cant seem to get it to pull the title of the url.  if its even possible